# What's wrong with this regular expression in a .htaccess file?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand why this regular expression isn't working in my .htaccess file. I want it so whenever a user goes to the `job_wanted.php?jid=ID`, they will be taken to `job/ID`.

What's wrong with this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^job_wanted\.php?$ job/%1? [R]
```

I want it so when a user clicks on http://localhost/jobwehave.co.za/jobs/ID they are shown the same results as what below would show http://localhost/jobwehave.co.za/jobs?id=ID.

Sorry for the mix up. I still very confused to how this works.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the user to be able to type in a RESTful URL like `/job/42` but that would be seen by your application as `job_wanted.php?jid=42`?

Comment: I think that's what I want. basicly so when a user clicks on a link like http://localhost/jobswehave/job_wanted.php?jid=42 the url is rewritten to http://localhost/jobswehave/job/4

Comment: Um, that conflicts with my comment. **Which URL style do you want users to see in their URL bar?**

Comment: http://localhost/jobswehave/job/4 that's the url I'm trying to show in the url bar

Comment: The query part, `?jid=9?`. is not available to `RewriteRule`. You need to use a `RewriteCond` statement to get at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is that you can't match the query string as part of `RewriteRule`. You need to move that part into a `RewriteCond` statement.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^job_wanted\.php$ /job/%1?
```

Editing to reflect your updated question, which is the opposite of what I've shown here. For the reverse, to convert `/job/123` into something your PHP script can consume, you'll want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/job/([0-9]+)$ /path/to/job_wanted.php?jid=$1
```

But you're probably going to have trouble putting this in an `.htaccess` file anywhere except the root, and maybe even there. If it works at the root, you'll likely need to strip the leading `/` from the `RewriteRule` I show here.

Second edit to reflect your comment: I think what you want is complicated, but this might work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/job/([0-9]+)$ /path/to/job_wanted.php?jid=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^job_wanted\.php$ http://host.name/job/%1? [R]
```

Your fundamental problem is that you want to "fix" existing links, presumably out of your control. In order to change the URL in the browser address bar, you must redirect the browser. There is no other way to do it.

That's what the second cond+rule does: it matches incoming old URLs and redirects to your pretty URL format. This either needs to go in a `VirtualHost` configuration block or in the `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your PHP script.

The first rule does the opposite: it converts the pretty URL back into something that Apache can use, but it does so using an internal sub-request that hopefully will not trigger another round of rewriting. If it does, you have an infinite loop. If it works, this will invoke your PHP script with a query string parameter for the job ID and your page will work as it has all along. Note that because this rule assumes a different, probably non-existent file system path, it must go in a `VirtualHost` block or in the `.htaccess` file at your site root, i.e. *a different location*.

Spreading the configuration around different places sounds like a recipe for future problems to me and I don't recommend it. I think you'll be better off to change the links under your control to the pretty versions and not worry about other links.

Comment: The OP stated the problem backwards. He wants to use RESTful-style URLs. Have a look at my answer - I think I've got it right (but I'm not all that familiar with `mod_rewrite` ;-).

Comment: still when I click on a localhost/jobswehave/job_wanted.php?jid=42 link it takes me to  localhost/jobswehave/job_wanted.php?jid=42 it's not making the url look like localhost/jobswehave/jobs/42 i have another rul so when a user goes to localhost/jobswehave/jobs it's showing the results from localhost/jobswehave/jobs.php

Comment: @Matthew, if I understand what you're trying to accomplish, I think you're confused. The point of the rewrite is that there wouldn't ***be*** a click on a link that looks like `localhost/jobswehave/job_wanted.php?jid=42`. All the links in the browser would look like `localhost/jobswehave/job/42`.

Comment: @Matthew, I've updated the answer to reflect what I think you're after, but I think you should reconsider your goals.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/job/([0-9]+)$ /jobwehave\.co\.za/job_wanted.php?jid=$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jid=([0-9]+)
    RewriteRule ^job_wanted\.php$ http://localhost/jobwehave\.co\.za/job/%1? [R]

still not working @Steve Madsen

Comment: You need to remove the leading `/` from the `ReWriteRule` pattern when this is on a per-directory basis (i.e. `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to escape special characters (like `?`)?

Answer (score 1):

The `?` and `.` characters have a special meaning in regular expressions. You probably just need to escape them.

Also, you need to capture the jid value and use it in the rule.

Try to change your rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^job_wanted\.php\?jid=([0-9]+)$ /job/$1
```

Comment: `RewriteRule` can't match against the query string; see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `?` and `.` marks if you want those to be literals.

```
^job_wanted\.php\?jid=9\?$
```

But although that explains why your pattern isn't matching, it doesn't address the issue of your URL rewriting. I'm also not sure why you want the `^` and `$` are there, since that will prevent it from matching most URLs (e.g. http://www.yoursite.com/job_wanted.php?jid=9 won't work because it doesn't start with job_wanted.php).

I don't know htaccess well, so I can only address the regex portion of your question. In traditional regex syntax, you'd be looking for something like this:

```
s/job_wanted\.php\?jid=(\d*)/job\/$1/i
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't captured the job ID in the regex, so you can't reference it in the rewritten URL. Something like this (not tested, caveat emptor, may cause gastric distress, etc.):

```
RewriteRule ^job/([0-9]+) job_wanted.php?jid=$1
```

See [Start Rewriting](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-syntax) for a tutorial on this.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` anchors the regex at the beginning of the string.

`RewriteRule` matches the URI **beginning** with a `/` (unless it's in some per-directory configuration area).

Either prefix the `/` or remove the anchor `^` (depending on what you want to achieve)

Comment: He said this is in an `.htaccess` file, so Apache will strip off the directory path leading up to and including the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
ReWriteRule ^job\_wanted\.php\?jid\=([0-9-]+)$ /job/$1
```

should do the trick.